# From a list of string, get a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings which contains spanish-recipes´s  ingredients and its quantities and I would like to get a list of dictionaries splitting every ingredient, unit and quantity.

This is the list:

```
ingredients=[
 '50',
 'ccs',
 'aceite',
 '1',
 'hoja',
 'laurel',
 '\n',
 '1',
 'cabeza',
 'ajos',
 '1',
 'vaso',
 'vino',
 '1,5',
 'kilos',
 'conejo',
 '\n',
...]
```

I would like to get a dict like this:

```
my_dic=[
{"name":"aceite" ,"qt":50 ,"unit": "ccs"},
{"name":"laurel" ,"qt":1 ,"unit": "hoja"},
{"name":"ajos" ,"qt":1 ,"unit": "cabeza"},
{"name":"vino" ,"qt":1 ,"unit": "vaso"},
{"name":"conejo" ,"qt":1,5 ,"unit": "kilos"}, 
...]
```

I have been trying things but it was all a disaster.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So, for each chunk of three consecutive items, you wish to produce a dict using those values? Are you able to produce the dict from the three items? Are you able to cut the list into chunks? Could you show at least one of the things you have been trying?

Comment: The output structure of dictionary which you have mentioned is not proper. That is invalid dictionary. Key can't be the same.

Comment: 1. Filter out `'\n'` 2. divide the list into chunks of size 3 3. Simple list comprehension like `[dict(zip(['name','qt','unit'],chunk)) for chunk in list]`

Comment: I just noticed, your initial `ingredients` data contains some `'\n'` elements, without any regular spacing. I assume you want to ignore those? Did you consider doing a separate pass first to remove those from the list?

Comment: @SaniyaParveez OP says "a dict" but appears to actually want a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

So first, you want to remove the newlines from your original list:

```py
ingredients = [i for i in ingredients if i is not '\n']
```

Then, each ingredient name is every third element in the `ingredients` list starting from the third element.  Likewise for the quantity and unit, starting from the second and first elements, respectively:

```py
names = ingredients[2::3]
units = ingredients[1::3]
qts = ingredients[::3]
```

Then, iterate through these lists and construct the data structure you specified (which is not actually a `dict` but a `list` of `dict`s):

```py
my_list = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    my_dict = {"name":names[i],"qt":qts[i],"unit":units[i]}
    my_list.append(my_dict)
```

There are a lot of ways to compress all of the above, but I have written it for comprehensibility.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
ingredients = (list)(filter(lambda a: a != '\n', ingredients))
ing_organized = []

for i in range (0, len(ingredients) , 3):
    curr_dict = {"name": ingredients[i+2] ,"qt": ingredients[i] ,"unit": ingredients[i+1]}
    ing_organized.append(curr_dict)
```

I just removed '\n' elements from the list as they didn't seem to have meaning.

Comment: this does not work, as ```a.remove("b")``` only removes the first instance of ```"b"``` in ```a```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't produce a dictionary, but it does give you the output that you specify in the question:

```
# Strip out the \n values (can possibly do this with a .strip() in the input stage)
ingredients = [value for value in ingredients if value != '\n']

labels = ['qt', 'unit', 'name']

my_dic = [dict(zip(labels, ingredients[i:i+3])) for i in range(0, len(ingredients), 3)]
```

`my_dic` contains:

```
[{'qt': '50', 'unit': 'ccs', 'name': 'aceite'},
 {'qt': '1', 'unit': 'hoja', 'name': 'laurel'},
 {'qt': '1', 'unit': 'cabeza', 'name': 'ajos'},
 {'qt': '1', 'unit': 'vaso', 'name': 'vino'},
 {'qt': '1,5', 'unit': 'kilos', 'name': 'conejo'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean you list with `filter` to remove the `\n` characters and then `zip()` it together to collect your items together. This makes a quick two-liner:

```
l = filter(lambda w: w != '\n', ingredients)

result = [{'name': name, 'qt':qt, 'unit': unit} 
          for qt, unit, name  in zip(l, l, l)]
```

result:

```
[{'name': 'aceite', 'qt': '50', 'unit': 'ccs'},
 {'name': 'laurel', 'qt': '1', 'unit': 'hoja'},
 {'name': 'ajos', 'qt': '1', 'unit': 'cabeza'},
 {'name': 'vino', 'qt': '1', 'unit': 'vaso'},
 {'name': 'conejo', 'qt': '1,5', 'unit': 'kilos'}]
```